# Проблема с сайтом на OpenServer

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, openserver

Доброе время суток !У меня возникает проблема со входом на мой сайт! [image: Помогите мне с этим , пожалуйста .]

Comment: а до этого вы заходили? откатывали назад изменения в коде?

Comment: у вас установлен DEBUG true?

Comment: Да до этого вход был . И Debug true установлен .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рекомендую для начала в корне папки, в файле wp-config, определить define( 'WP_DEBUG', true ); тогда вы увидите ошибку на сайте.. если все чисто и все равно дает критическую ошибку, перезагрузите сервер или возможно вы внесли изменения файлы, которые работают с БД

Comment: Не подскажете как как перезагрузить сервер ? Если просто найти в трей ярлык OpenServer и там нажать на перезагрузку , то не помогло .

Comment: Зайдите в админ базы, и посмотрите вашу базу и option, там все нормально?

Comment: Вы пробовали зайти в админу?

Comment: Да я заходил в phpMyAdmin .  Проблем не вижу .

Comment: в таблице option, там надо смотреть. Вы не удаляли файлы или код.

Comment: и гляньте настройки сервера